# How to show second text, if first text is null in sap UI5

Tags: sapui5

**Controller.js**

```
table.bindItems({
    path: "/",
    template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells: [
            new sap.m.Text({
                text: "{account} ? {recieverAddress} "
            }),
        ]
    })
});
```

Here I have to show "recieverAddress", if "account" is null. How to do this in sap ui5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use expression binding:

```
text: "{= ${account} ? ${account} : ${recieverAddress} }"
```

more info here: https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0